# Linux message loops and waiting for events without blocking current thread

Tags: linux, multithreading

How can we implement the following function for linux-like operating systems?

The function has already been running on any windows version (Windows 98+) for about 15 years. It imitates multi-threading in a single thread and runs in both single or multi threading models, without blocking the invoking thread while waiting for the events. Recursive calls and returns may happen depending on outer-events but this simple function has always worked fine so far. The same logic MAY NOT be possible in linux, but a similar approach would be appreciable. (I haven't changed any letter of the function to keep it as it is. The variable names are a mixture of Turkish and English)

Thanks in advance!

```
ERes __fastcall Bekle(HANDLE obj, int mls, int mod)
{
    JMSG  msg;
    DWORD ret, son = GetTickCount()+mls;

    while(0 <= mls)
    {
        ret = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &obj, FALSE, mls, mod);
        if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
             return wrOlur;      // The obj was signaled
        if (ret == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
             return wrSaat;      // Time expired event
        if (ret == WAIT_ABANDONED_0)
             return wrTerk;      // Abandoned
        if (ret == WAIT_FAILED)
             return wrFail;      // Failed anyway
        if (ret == 0xFFFFFFFF)
             return wrHata;      // Error returned

        while(PeekMessage(msg,NULL,NULL,NULL,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(msg);
            DispatchMessage(msg);
            if(WaitForSingleObject(obj, 0)==WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                return wrOlur; // Event is now signaled.
        }
        mls = son - GetTickCount();
    }

    return wrSaat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the sample code that appears to be anything complicated. This looks like a typical message dispatching loop, and it would work exactly the same in Linux as it would in Windows, presuming you had some kind of a message queue that's being read from.

Additionally, POSIX specifies the poll() and select() system calls (you can find all the details by searching Google) which wait for any one of several file descriptors to become readable or writable. This is another way that single thread-based event dispatching gets typically implemented in Linux. You can poll() or select() to check if one or more file descriptors can be read or written from. If not, do something else, then try again. Otherwise, read whatever's to be read or written to, from the appropriate file descriptor, then move on.

Comment: The key point is the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects function which wakes up the current thread for any type of event. POSIX messaging functions do not support a similar behavior. They work on predefined events. My function is not used as a single waiting point, instead many event objects and classes implements their own handlers and  all use the same function (Bekle,(handle, period, mode)) as the final common system specific END-POINT of event catching.

Comment: Who said anything about POSIX messaging functions? POSIX messaging functions are actually not used very often, in practice. poll()/select() with multiple file descriptors is the standard way this kind of thing is implemented.